# Confusion about the convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I have the following question here:

> Determine whether the following sequence is convergent of divergent.
> $$x_1=\cos(1), \text{and }x_n=\max(x_{n-1},\cos(n))$$
> for $n\geq 2$.
> Fully justify.

> Note that $\max(a,b)$ equals the larger of the numbers $a$ and $b$.

Now I could be wrong about this but since the cosine function is always bounded between $-1$ and $1$, it has to converge right?

I'm just confused about the sequence because it seems that $x_n$ will $\textbf{ALWAYS}$ be $\cos(1).$

For example, $x_1=\cos(1)$. $x_2=\max\{x_1,\cos(2)\}$. However, $\cos(1)>\cos(2)$ so that means $x_2=\cos(1)$.  By similar logic, we get $x_3=\cos(1),x_4=\cos(1)\dots x_{n+1}=\cos(1)$. So it will always be the same value for the entire sequence right?

I guess that does mean the sequence technically converges but it just feels a little odd.

Comment: You seem to assume that $\cos n>\cos (n+1)$ for all $n$.

Comment: But cos(6)>cos(1).

Comment: $\cos(x) = 1$ iff $x=2k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$. Since $n$ will get arbitrarily close to such $2k\pi$ (which is irrational), it means that $\cos n$ will get arbitrarily close to $1$ for $n$ large enough. There will never be an $n=2k\pi$ (because of the irrationality; except for $k=0$), but it will get arb close.

Comment: Oh. That was silly. Yes that makes sense. Thank you @geetha290krm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence $\{\cos n\}$ is not monotonic. The sequence $\{x_n\}$ will gradually approach $1$, here are the notable values for $n\le 100$:

- $x_1=0.540\ldots$
- $x_6=0.960\ldots$
- $x_{19}=0.9887\ldots$
- $x_{25}=0.9912\ldots$
- $x_{44}=0.99984\ldots$

**Comment.** Note that $\cos x = 1$ iff $x = 2k\pi$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. Since $\pi$ is irrational, this means that $2k\pi$ will never be an integer (except for $k=0$), so there will never be an $n$ that is equal to some $2k\pi$, so $\cos n\neq 1$ for all $n \in\mathbb N^*$.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, I want to point out that, while knowning about $\cos(n)$ getting as close to $1$ as wanted is a useful fact, knowing this is not strictly necessary to solve the problem. That's because the problem does not ask for value of the limit, only if it exists or not!

As you said, $\cos(n)$ is bounded, and so is your sequence $(x_n)$. Not every bounded sequence converges, of course, but in addition, as it is defined, $(x_n)$ is monotonic ($\forall n \ge 1: x_{n+1} \ge x_n$). But a monotonic and bounded (in the direction of the monotony) sequence is always converging, that's the [monotonic convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

Using that theorem, you can immediately also solve the problem if $\cos(n)$ is replaced by $\cos(f(n))$ where $f(n)$ is any real valued function of $n$. If for example $f(n)=n^{10}e^n$, then it will be much harder to find the limit, but using the monotonic convergence theorem it is easy to see that a limit must exist.